# Firefox / GeckoView Gamepad API not functional?

Tags: android, firefox, gamepad, gamepad-api, geckoview

The [Gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API) isn't working in the official firefox app and in a GeckoView (v 107.0.xxx) on Android.

To Reproduce: Open the test gamepad API site: https://luser.github.io/gamepadtest/
On chrome, it shows a connected gamepad. On firefox, it does not.

Tested with:
Google Pixel 6, Samsung Galaxy A32, LG G8

Using: Xbox one controller and PS5DualShock controller (wired and wireless).

`navigator.getGamepads()` seems to just return an empty array.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and have a workaround? Or perhaps something obvious I'm missing? If not, where would we report a bug like this? Thanks

Comment: Interestingly, if I disconnect and reconnect the controller while on the test page, then it will recognize it and map the axes and dpad correctly. But the A, B, X, Y buttons aren't mapped (on both controllers I tested). Note, pressing buttons does not trigger the gamepad to be connected, I have to physically disconnect and reconnect it to trigger the gamepadconnected event

Comment: Never found a solution. I got around this by grabbing button presses in the android app and passing them to the webview via js.